# HTTP redirect to HTTPS on IIS (ASP.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net, iis, https

When browsing my site **http://example.site.com** IIS redirects the user to **https://example.site.com:44345**

I know it comes from the web.config file:
`<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44345" />`

How do I change the port value to 443 when I want to publish my (production) site to an IIS?

Comment: Why cannot you change your web.config? That redirection comes from ASP.NET Core framework, not IIS.

Comment: I think the redirection come from    app.UseHttpsRedirection(); If you wanna access the website via 443 port and https://localhost. Please add an https binding host header in your IIS.

Comment: If have the correct bindings in IIS. The question is how do I update the web.config programatically? If I change it manually it gets automatically changed to 44345 on build.

Comment: What aboutdisable usehttpsredirection() and use URL rewrite rule instead?https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

1. Open *IIS*.
2. Right click on your application and choose *Edit Bindings*.

[image]

3. New window will open. Click *Add*.
4. Choose *Type* ***https***.

[image]

5. Reset the application.

Comment: It works when surfing to https, but redirects to https://:44345 when surfing to http://. The 44345 is in the web.config that gets autoupdated on build.